# Play 2.2.4 externalized config file

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

According to the documentation an application build with the task `play dist` should be able to be externalized configured using `-Dconfig.file=c:\conf\application.prod.conf` but whatever i do the `-Dconfig.file` option seems to have totally no effect and the default application.conf inside the packaged jar seems to be loaded.

Any clue on how to use the externalized config in a Play 2.2.4 application?

Comment: Stupid tag... choose better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Heroku we use an environment variable to determine which config to use. Like this:

web: target/universal/stage/bin/theapp -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Dconfig.resource=${ENVIRONMENT}.conf ${JAVA_OPTS}

Locally I guess you could run it like this (note the quotes!):

```
$ activator "run -Dconfig.file=/Users/durre/conf/application.conf"
```

Maybe replace "activator" with "play". I forgot when they switched to activator.

Comment: Using Linux this seems to work for Windows we needed to do some adjustments to the start script.